# Разные части SVG картинки, как разные ссылки

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

Картинка состоит из нескольких объектов, допустим, квадрат и круг. Хотелось бы, чтобы при нажатии на круг происходил переход на один сайт, при нажатии на квадрат на другой сайт. Можно ли как-то это реализовать?

Answer (score 6):

Квадрат или прямоугольник в svg это код внутри тегов `<rect>`. Поэтому именно этот тег нужно обернуть в теги ссылки. Они немного отличаются от тегов HTML

`<a xlink:href="https://yandex.ru/" class="yandex-search">`

> Современные браузеры уже поддерживают ссылку  в svg, как в html
>      `<a> href="https://yandex.ru/" class="yandex-search">`
>    но лучше пока
>   воздержаться от этого, так как в `safari` это  не работает.

При наведении на объект svg всплывает туллтип - подсказка. Это текст, который находится внутри тегов `<title>`

Ниже полный код для двух элементов SVG c разными ссылками на каждом из них.

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="370" height="460" viewBox="0 0 370 460" >  
 <a xlink:href="https://yandex.ru/" class="yandex-search" > 
 <title> ссылка на Yandex </title>
<rect x="50" y="50" width="50%" height="50%" rx="5%" fill="purple" />
</a>
<a xlink:href="https://google.ru/" class="google-search" > 
 <title> ссылка на Google </title>

<circle cx="180" cy="110" r="50" fill="dodgerblue" />
</svg>
```

*В сниппете ссылки не работают из-за требований безопасности, но если вы скачаете файл и сохраните его в формате `HTML`,то ссылки будут рабочими.*

Comment: @tttyyyrrrryyy Если ответ был вам полезен и проблема решена, то отметьте его галкой (около цифры ответа)

Answer (score 3):

### Вариант с анимацией  CSS  ссылок

```css
.google {
  fill: dodgerblue;
  transition: 1.5s;
}

.yandex {
  fill: purple;
  transition: 1.5s;
}

.yandex:hover,
.google:hover {
  fill: gold;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="370" height="460" viewBox="0 0 370 460">  
 <a xlink:href="https://yandex.ru/" class="yandex-search" > 
 <title> ссылка на Yandex </title>
<rect class="yandex" x="50" y="50" width="50%" height="50%" rx="5%" />
</a>
<a xlink:href="https://google.ru/" class="google-search" > 
 <title> ссылка на Google </title>

<circle class="google" cx="180" cy="110" r="50" />
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

обернуть изображение в тег `<a href="ссылка"><img/></a>`